# How do I get the current date in Javascript, using an argument

Tags: javascript, date

There are loads of questions about the current date in JavaScript in general, but in my scenario, I have to pass in something to the date object, because usually there is a valid date I'm looking for. However, my question is - assuming the argument is undefined, what should I pass to mimic new Date()?

As an example, my code will do something like this.

```
const date = '2019-11-26T19:10:12.000Z'
const diff = new Date(date).getTime() - new Date().getTime()
```

While my components are rendering, I need to give date an initial value (while it loads from the server). During this initial loading time, I expect the diff to equal 0.

I have tried the following

```
new Date(undefined) >> Invalid Date

new Date('') >> Invalid Date

new Date(null) >> Thu Jan 01 1970

new Date(0) >> Thu Jan 01 1970
```

I'm trying to solve it in a simple way, by passing in whatever value would match no argument for Date. It seems weird, but if it's the case, I'll just assume it's JavaScript date objects being weird.

Comment: *Why* do you "have to pass in something"?  If you have weird requirements it helps to explain in more detail.

Comment: `var d = arg ? new Date(arg) : new Date()`

Comment: `new Date(new Date)` works, but I don't see why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Have updated my question

Comment: Thanks @TiiJ7 - that's what I was looking for, please post that as the answer so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: What test framework do you use? It seems like spy can help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: In this case I need to update the code to work as expected, ie it's not an issue with the testing itself, but thanks for suggesting. I'm using jest though. I've updated my question to reflect this, since I saw it was confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your date with another date object as parameter.

```js
var params = new Date;
var date = new Date(params);

console.log(date)
```

Comment: In the comments on the question, you said this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense now.

Comment: `new Date` returns a string, which must then be parsed back to a value to generate a date. It makes mores sense to me to use `var params = Date.now()`, which returns the current time value and avoids creating the string and subsequent parsing.